# Как в файл txt записать данные в определённую строку

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Как записать данные в определённую строку файла?

Файл `Hello.txt`:

```
Приве
Друг
```

Как добавить букву `т` в первую строку?

```py
f = open("Hello.txt", "a")
f.write("т")
f.close()
```

Ведь аргумент `a` добавляет элементы в конец последней строки.

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Дайте больше информации. Например, блок кода и данные, которые содержаться и которые добавляете [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1302159/edit).

Answer (score 6):

Открыть файл, считать его в память, произвести необходимые манипуляции с текстом, сохранить полученный текст в файл.

Просто добавить что-то куда-то в середину файла нельзя, потому что весь текст после этого места должен быть сдвинут, и сам по себе он не сдвинется. Представьте файл как длинную полку с книгами. Можно легко добавить еще одну книгу в самом конце (это делает `а`), но нельзя просто так вставить книгу в середине, потому что там нет места.

Answer (score 6):

Нельзя добавить данные в произвольное место файла. Но Вы можете прочитать содержимое, изменить его и записать заново.

***Пример:***

```py
with open('Hello.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines[0] = lines[0].rstrip() + 'т\n'

    f.seek(0)
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: большое спасибо